# what's the meaning of _ in this scala code?

Tags: scala

What's the meaning of "`_`" in `Seq[Dependency[_]]` and `RDD[_]` for the following code

```
abstract class RDD[T: ClassTag](
    @transient private var sc: SparkContext,
    @transient private var deps: Seq[Dependency[_]]
  ) extends Serializable with Logging {

  /** Construct an RDD with just a one-to-one dependency on one parent */
  def this(@transient oneParent: RDD[_]) =
    this(oneParent.context , List(new OneToOneDependency(oneParent)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a wildcard.
You can use a wildcard for a type parameter.

> **Quantification**
>
> Sometimes you do not care to be able to name a type variable, for
>   example:
>
> ```
> scala> def count[A](l: List[A]) = l.size
> count: [A](List[A])Int
> ```
>
> Instead you can use “wildcards”:
>
> ```
> scala> def count(l: List[_]) = l.size
> count: (List[_])Int
> ```
>
> This is shorthand for:
>
> ```
> scala> def count(l: List[T forSome { type T }]) = l.size
> count: (List[T forSome { type T }])Int
> ```

From http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html

Comment: Is RDD[_] in def this(@transient oneParent: RDD[_]) the same as RDD[T]? Since class is abstract class RDD[T: ClassTag], and it defined T.